# Parenting/Constraints problem for animation using Snow character

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm new to Blender and trying to do an animation with the character [Snow](https://studio.blender.org/characters/snow/v2/) (which seems super nice).
I'm trying to parent it to a bicycle but each time I go in the *Add Object Constraint* tab and add the child of it, Blender just puts the constraint on all the root or global. It does seem that when I select the different controls, the name never changes and stays to RIG-Snow.

Comment: Hi Atsumi, can u pls provide a blend file so we can see what you have done? thx.

Comment: Hi Chris! I put the scene in this zip file. And the bike rig that is linked into the file so I think it will go well.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zu5VPhQ8ePfvfp7MHMStNCb3PsEWA8lw/view?usp=sharing
Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: By the way I was trying to parent the character's foot to the pedal ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i wanna say - even if you hate me for this - but this is NOT a good start to start with Blender. Why not? Because Blender isn't intuitive, it is hard for beginner to learn it and the project is too complicated to begin with. Of course you can try to do it, but it will be frustrating because you will have to ask a lot of questions - and if you are lucky you will get answers and if you are a bit luckier you will understand the answers and you can use them.

I would recommend to watch beginner rigging tutorials and beginner tutorials about Blender. A good start are these: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/
After you tried out a bit i would watch and rebuild some beginner rigging tutorials.

Now to your problem:

The add object constraint makes no sense at all here, because it constraints an object (that's just one of many problem you have: you don't know what is what and when to use what). An object e.g. is an armature. Or a cube. But you want to constraint just a part of the armature (else you are moving the whole armature (and by this snow)). That's why you need a bone constraint here.
So you have to

1. select the right armature in object mode (snow)
2. go to pose mode
3. select the right bone of your armature (IK-MSTR-Foot.R)
4. goto bone constraints
5. add bone constraint: copy location

[image]

use the bone B_PedalD as bone target

then you will get:

result:

[image]

Note:

I did NOT use the velo you "somehow" imported into your file. I imported it myself. If you do the import wrong - it won't work.

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for the help it works indeed! It's true Blender is quite hard to grasp and the changing versions also makes it hard to find the right tutorials (I'm talking for exemple about linking objects/characters to import them as references in a scene that's why maybe my set up is a bit messy).
Nonetheless I'm getting there slowly as I already rigged the bike myself but I guess I missed the explanation about the armature being a whole object it's quite different from maya.
So thanks again for the help I'll definitely check out more tutorials :)